# Can I use jQuery to show when my Ajax query is in progress?

Tags: jquery

I am using the following javascript to detect when a field is changed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("select[id^='Status_'], input[id^='Position_']").change(function (e) {
            var type = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[0];
            updateField('Account', $(this), type);
        });
    });
</script>
```

This then calls the following to updata data in the database:

```
function updateField(entity, obj, type) {
    var val = obj.val();
    var idArr = obj.attr("id");
    var idTmp = idArr.split("_");
    var id = idTmp[1];
    var pk = $('#Meta_PartitionKey').val();
    var rk = $("div[id='rk_" + id + "']").html();
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: "/Administration/" + entity + "s/Update",
        data: {
            pk: pk,
            rk: rk,
            fld: type,
            val: val
        }
    });
};
```

Is there some way that I could provide a visual clue to the user that the update is taking place. Something like changing the cursor and then changing it back.

Also how can I give a message to show if the update failed to my users?

Comment: You can use beforeSend() to generate some kind of alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
function updateField(entity, obj, type) {
    var val = obj.val();
    var idArr = obj.attr("id");
    var idTmp = idArr.split("_");
    var id = idTmp[1];
    var pk = $('#Meta_PartitionKey').val();
    var rk = $("div[id='rk_" + id + "']").html();
    enableLoadingIcon();
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: "/Administration/" + entity + "s/Update",
        data: {
            pk: pk,
            rk: rk,
            fld: type,
            val: val
        },
        success: function()
        {
            disableLoadingIcon();
        }
    });
};
```

And then implement the two functions enableLoading and disableLoading to show a loading icon or anything.

For example implement css styled to change the cursor for the whole body:

```
body.ajaxloading {
    cursor:wait;
}
```

See here for examples: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp

And then implement the functions like this:

```
function enableLoadingIcon() {
    $(body).addClass('ajaxloading');
}
function disableLoadingIcon() {
    $(body).addClass('ajaxloading');
}
```

Comment: This looks good. Have you seen any examples of these kind of functions? Is there some way that I could just change the cursor type?

Comment: You can specify a loading cursor in you css for example for body.ajaxloading and then implement the two functions to set/unset the class to the body tag... i'll edit the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use some jQuery library, then this helps: [blockUI](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/)

Answer (score 1):

before calling updateField function show some image ( can generate nice here http://www.ajaxload.info/ ) and after success hide it.

in $.ajax you can use success and error.

Answer (score 1):

Before you call you `$.ajax()` display an element that has an animation or message for loading, and in the `$.ajax()` add a success handler:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function() {
       alert('done');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use blockUI in connection with the callback function of ajax.

```
function updateField(entity, obj, type) {
$.blockUI();
var val = obj.val();
var idArr = obj.attr("id");
var idTmp = idArr.split("_");
var id = idTmp[1];
var pk = $('#Meta_PartitionKey').val();
var rk = $("div[id='rk_" + id + "']").html();
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: "/Administration/" + entity + "s/Update",
    data: {
        pk: pk,
        rk: rk,
        fld: type,
        val: val
    },
    success: function(){
        $.unblockUI();
    }
});
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function updateField(entity, obj, type) {
    var val = obj.val();
    var idArr = obj.attr("id");
    var idTmp = idArr.split("_");
    var id = idTmp[1];
    var pk = $('#Meta_PartitionKey').val();
    var rk = $("div[id='rk_" + id + "']").html();
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: "/Administration/" + entity + "s/Update",
        data: {
            pk: pk,
            rk: rk,
            fld: type,
            val: val
        },
        beforeSend: function(){
          alert('Starting ajax');
        }
        success: function(response){
         alert('finished');
        }
    });
};
```

You would also have to handle the error situation but this should be enough to get you started

Comment: The users will make many changes to the screens. Thanks for taking the time to help but they will kill me if they see alert boxes popping up for every start and end of an update.

Comment: The alert boxes are just an example, you can change this code to whatever you wish